Why does the variable set with fw_setenv in OpenBMC disappear after reboot while others persist?
I'm encountering an issue with OpenBMC where I'm setting a variable using the fw_setenv command, but it disappears after a reboot. Strangely, other variables I set using the same method persist across reboots.
For example, I'm setting a variable openbmconce with the value factory-reset using the command:
fw_setenv openbmconce factory-reset;

However, upon reboot, this variable seems to vanish.
It's worth noting that OpenBMC's factory reset functionality typically involves deleting the read-write layer. However, I've modified its behavior at the code level to do nothing. Despite this, the openbmconce variable still disappears after reboot.
I've noticed that certain variables might be intentionally designed to reset upon reboot for security or temporary configuration purposes, but I couldn't find any documentation specifying this behavior for openbmconce.
Could anyone provide insights or guidance on how to configure other variables in OpenBMC to exhibit this behavior, similar to openbmconce?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Does it imply saving the environment on the storage?

No, it does not necessarily mean saving on storage. The behavior of the variable openbmconce disappearing after a reboot is likely related to how OpenBMC handles certain environment variables, particularly those tied to system events like factory resets.
In my case, the factory reset functionality typically deletes the read-write layer, which may affect certain environment variables. Even though I modified the factory reset behavior to do nothing, the openbmconce variable still resets.

My English is not good, use the translation, sorry

I think I know what's going on. This variable is maintained by the systemd service, clear-once.server, which is a one-time service that runs only once when the system kernel is started, and whose source code shows that the openbmconce variable is cleared.
[Unit]
Description=Clear one time boot overrides

ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/fw_env.config
RequiresMountsFor=/run /sbin /etc

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

# It took 7 seconds to erase and write flash, be conservative
TimeoutStartSec=60
Restart=no

ExecStart=/sbin/fw_setenv openbmconce
ExecStart=/sbin/fw_setenv openbmconce

